# Group by odd results

Tags: sql, group-by

I am running the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  CAST(ar_all_bills.a_unpaid_balance as decimal(5,2)) as "Total Unpaid Balance" 
FROM ar_all_bills WHERE a_ar_customer_cid = 100059
```

The result is the following 2 records:

```
49.74
62.41
```

However, when I add a `GROUP BY` to the query to get the `SUM` of the unpaid balance:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  SUM(CAST(ar_all_bills.a_unpaid_balance as decimal(5,2))) as "Total Unpaid Balance" 
FROM ar_all_bills  WHERE a_ar_customer_cid = 100059 GROUP BY a_ar_customer_cid
```

The result is:

```
461.27
```

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 7):

Your `DISTINCT` in the first query is filtering out items that are being included in the `SUM` in the second query.  Remove that `DISTINCT` and you'll see that the sum from the first will equal the sum from the second.

If you want the `SUM` to match the original, try this:

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT CAST(ar_all_bills.a_unpaid_balance as decimal(5,2))) as "Total Unpaid Balance" FROM ar_all_bills  WHERE a_ar_customer_cid = 100059 GROUP BY a_ar_customer_cid
```

The `DISTINCT` needs to be inside the `SUM`, not outside it.  Otherwise, you're getting the `DISTINCT` `SUM`, not the `SUM` of `DISTINCT` items.

If you want the `SUM` to be of all the items (not just the `DISTINCT` ones), then just remove the `DISTINCT` altogether (no different than your second query in your specific situation, but different in meaning over all situations):

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(ar_all_bills.a_unpaid_balance as decimal(5,2))) as "Total Unpaid Balance" FROM ar_all_bills  WHERE a_ar_customer_cid = 100059 GROUP BY a_ar_customer_cid
```

Comment: You are absolutely right.  Thanks so much for the quick response!

Comment: You may want to note that DISTINCT doesn't need to be there at all.

Comment: @NickVaccaro:  Thanks; filled that in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the first query without `DISTINCT` then post results.  That should show you what's wrong.

Comment: Lots of duplicates in there, I did find that I can include a line number in my where statement to include the values only once.  Thanks to everyone involved.

49.74,
49.74,
49.74,
62.41,
62.41,
62.41,
62.41,
62.41